# Google Maps Embed Issue - 403 On HTTPS requests but Works Fine on HTTP requests

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-api-2

For example:

*https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=38.890390,-77.084140&zoom=12&size=220x220&maptype=roadmap?key=xxxx*
returns a 403

but

*http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=38.890390,-77.084140&zoom=12&size=220x220&maptype=roadmap?key=xxxx*
works fine, but obviously this is not a solution because it will caused mix content issues on a secured site.

This only happens when embedding in a page, getting served the linking directly works.

Anyone more knowledgable than me run into this issue with Google before?

Comment: I have not 403 using https  ..  check better

Comment: @scaisEdge When request the https resource directly it loads fine.  Only embedded as an img src causes it to 403

Comment: show the code  ..

Comment: <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=38.890390,-77.084140&amp;zoom=12&amp;size=220x220&amp;maptype=roadmap?key=xxx"> works fine for me.  BTW this is a Static Maps API call, as opposed to the Maps Embed API.  What was the nature of your 403 error?   Are you over quota?